# Evaluate Excel Formulas - Flutter

Tags: excel, flutter, dart, mobile, excel-formula

Does anyone know some library to evaluate Excel formulas in Dart?
For example, I have this excel formula: `0.75*IF(4=1,1,0)+0.25*2501/4` and I want my dart code to evaluate it.

I only use `IF` and `IFERROR` functions.

Thank you.

Comment: IF(4=1,1,0) will always evaluate to zero, so your first term drops out completely.

Comment: "IF(4=1,1,0)" is just an example. Could be IF("AA"="AB",1,0)

Comment: So provide relevant and clear examples of what you want to achieve, as we can only understand what you show - we cannot read your mind.